How to get minimal space after \TblrNote?
Please consider the following (not so small) MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}  % real page layout is unknown

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\SetTblrStyle{note-tag}{font=\bfseries\scriptsize\kern 0.5pt}
%\SetTblrStyle{note}{align=right, hang = 1.2em}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}
%\begin{wide}
\caption{Protokoli višjih plasti v CAN omrežjih}   
\label{tab:CAN.protocoli}
    \begin{talltblr}[
        entry=none,     % <---
        label=none,     % <---
note{a} = {UDS: Universal Diagnostic Services},
note{b} = {CCP/XCP: CAN Calibration Protocol/Extended Calibration Protocol},
                    ]{colsep   = 4pt,
                      colspec  = {@{} *{2}{X} @{}},
                      cells = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                      row{1,3} = {c, font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
                     }
    \toprule
UDS &   OBD2       \\   
   \midrule
Protokol UDS\TblrNote{a} uporabljamo za diagnostiko vozlišč, nadgradnjo njihove programske opreme, preizkušanje programov in drugo. 
                &   Protokol CCP/XCP\TblrNote{b} omogoča vpisovanje/branje podatkov v vozliščih v postopkih kalibracije, merjenja spremenljivk za katere so zadolžene in opozarjanje na probleme.
                            \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
%\end{wide}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

It gives:

My problem is that space after \TblrNote{a} hasn't some minimal size (like space between words) and consequently the text which follow it touch \TblrNote{a}. Is there a some simple way to prevent this? For example by setting \TblrNote style? Writing for example \TblrNote{a}\quad each time is quite annoying.

Quick hack:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}  % real page layout is unknown

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\AddToHook{cmd/TblrNote/after}{\quad}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}
%\begin{wide}
\caption{Protokoli višjih plasti v CAN omrežjih}   
\label{tab:CAN.protocoli}
    \begin{talltblr}[
        entry=none,     % <---
        label=none,     % <---
note{a} = {UDS: Universal Diagnostic Services},
note{b} = {CCP/XCP: CAN Calibration Protocol/Extended Calibration Protocol},
                    ]{colsep   = 4pt,
                      colspec  = {@{} *{2}{X} @{}},
                      cells = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                      row{1,3} = {c, font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
                     }
    \toprule
UDS &   OBD2       \\   
   \midrule
Protokol UDS\TblrNote{a} uporabljamo za diagnostiko vozlišč, nadgradnjo njihove programske opreme, preizkušanje programov in drugo. 
                &   Protokol CCP/XCP\TblrNote{b} omogoča vpisovanje/branje podatkov v vozliščih v postopkih kalibracije, merjenja spremenljivk za katere so zadolžene in opozarjanje na probleme.
                            \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
%\end{wide}
    \end{table}

\end{document}



Tank you very much!

@Zarko You're welcome!
